# Moving index from one column to another in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reindex

I get a `DataFrame` from a library with an index already set to one of the data columns. What would be the easiest way to set it to another column, preserving the original index column.

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],columns=['a','b','c'])
df = df.set_index('a')

   b  c
a      
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

Output: (f.e. changing index from column `a` to column `b`)

```
   a  c
b      
2  1  3
5  4  6
8  7  9
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chain `reset_index` and then `set_index`:

```
df = df.reset_index().set_index('b')
```

**Or** separately:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index('b', inplace=True)
```

Resulting df

```
   a  c
b      
2  1  3
5  4  6
8  7  9
```